SOAP API in Laravel framework - cannot return response in an appriopriate format
i'm developing SOAP API in Laravel framework v 11, php 8.3.
this is my controller:
public function handleSoapRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $wsdlPath = storage_path('wsdl/wsdl.xml');

        $server = new Server($wsdlPath, [
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        ]);

        $server->setObject(new SoapService();

        $server->handle();
    }

Here is a mocked response of my SoapService:
public function SaveConfirmations($request): array
    {

        $results = [];
        $result = [
            'ErrorInfo' => false,
            'IsSuccess' => true,
            'ReferenceId' => 15
        ];
        $results[] = $result;

        return [
            'SaveConfirmationsResult' => $results
        ];
    }

And my response is:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SNInterface.DTO" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:SaveConfirmationResponse>
         <ns2:SaveConfirmationResult>
            <ns1:OperationResultById>
               <ns1:ErrorInfo/>
               <ns1:IsSuccess>true</ns1:IsSuccess>
               <ns1:ReferenceId>15</ns1:ReferenceId>
            </ns1:OperationResultById>
         </ns2:SaveConfirmationResult>
      </ns2:SaveConfirmationResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

in general the structure is correct, but expected response should be like that:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:snin="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/wsdl.DTO">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SaveConfirmationResponse>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:SaveConfirmationResult>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <snin:OperationResultById>
               <snin:ErrorInfo>?</snin:ErrorInfo>
               <snin:IsSuccess>?</snin:IsSuccess>
               <snin:ReferenceId>?</snin:ReferenceId>
            </snin:OperationResultById>
         </tem:SaveConfirmationResult>
      </tem:SaveInboundConfirmationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Im missing header and the prefixes are different. I totally cannot modify prefixes. The desired response is generated in soap ui from wsdl file.
How to fix that and change SOAP-ENV, ns2, ns1 and so on?
I've already tried different scenarios of response.
